# How to check how many test cases run on specific day in Jira

Tags: testing, jira, jira-xray

I use jira for my test management and almost 30+ tester work in the project. I would like to know is there any method I can filter out the test cases executed on a specific day [ say today ]. It can be any status passed / failed etc. In my test plan there are many test executions run in parallel. I tried to use the test run report feature from Xray but seems I cannot filter only finish day, which leads to wrong results it pull the test cases from previous days too.  If I give start date and finish date same, its not fetching the data executed today. Please help

Comment: To be able to help you out, can you please clarify if you're using Xray on Jira datacenter or Xray on Jira Cloud? If you don't know, can you please ask your Jira administrator?

Comment: Hi Sergio, I am using Xray on Jira Datacenter. Not on cloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several ways to achieved this.
The first one is to use the [Test Runs List gadget](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Test+Runs+List+Gadget) in a Jira dashboard.
Start by creating a saved filter for the Test Executions that you wish to process (e.g., all the Test Executions on project CALC).
[image: saved filter for obtaining the Test Executions on a project]

Then go to a Jira dashboard and add the "Test Runs List" gadget, and enable date range filtering.
[image: Test Runs List gadget configuration]

Then you will be able to see the list of Tests executed today, using the previous configuration.
[image: Test Runs List gadget example]

In Xray Datacenter you can also take advantage of [JQL functions](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Enhanced+querying+with+JQL) to perform some queries. In this case, the **testExecutionTests** JQL function; it accepts either a saved filter id or a Test Execution issue key.

Let's say we want to know the list of tests executed on 2024-01-15, in the scope of some Test Execution "CALC-390":

```
issuetype = 'Test' and issue in testExecutionTests('CALC-390', '', '', 'false', '', '', '', '>=2024-01-15', '<2024-01-16')
```

As an example, consider the following Test Execution with 2 tests executed today (2024-01-15).

[image: Test Execution issue with 2 tests executed on a given day]

This would be the JQL we could use on the issue search page, returning the 2 tests.

[image: JQL search for tests executed on a given day]

Lastly, you could also use a BI like tool, such as [eazyBI](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Integration+with+eazyBI) that can process Xray data. However, this requires an additional paid plugin to achieve it.

Comment: thanks for the wonderful explanation with detailed screenshots. I have tried with option one and it is working fine. Option 2, the Jqry is not working for me, I wish to fix that issue as well. I am getting error "The 'testExecutionTests' takes at least one argument and at most five arguments". Can you please tell me how can I fix it, I am using xray version 5.1.7

Comment: You're welcome. You have a rather old version of Xray. The documentation page in this case should be this one, which doesnt support filtering by dates according to it: https://docs.getxray.app/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=68409554#content/view/68409554  . Therefore jql may not be an option for you. All the best!